# What does bounded partial derivatives exactly mean?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

This might be a naive question, but if I give myself a continuously differentiable function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is said to have bounded partial derivatives, does this mean that the $i$-th partial derivative ($i\in\{1,...,n\}$) is bounded by a constant depending on $i$, or are all the partial derivatives bounded by the same constant?

Comment: does it really matter? these are only finite many bounds.

Comment: @user251257 I am asking because I want to know if I can use the norm $\|f''\|$ or do I need to use $\|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\|$ for each $i$

Comment: Assuming you use the euclidean norm then $\max_{1\le i \le n} \|\partial f / \partial x_i \| \le \| f' \| \le \sqrt{n}\max_{1\le i \le n}\|  \partial f / \partial x_i \|$. So it really doesn't matter. You can always assume the bounds are the same without loss of generality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Clearly the two statements are equivalent in this case.

If, in some more general case, you were told that you are given a set $F$ of bounded functions, then you should only assume that the functions are individually bounded.

Comment: so in general without any further precision it would only make sense to consider the norm $\|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\|$ for each $i$ rather than the norm $\|f'\|$ (I am considering sup norms)

Comment: @user223935: why are you writing about $f''$ when $f$ is only $C^1$? Is that just a typo?

Comment: @user251257 edited

Comment: but if all the partials are bounded then certainly $\|f'\|$ is so it cmes to the same thing.

Comment: @Chilango yes I understand it is equivalent in the end, I guess my question is more of a convention thing, whether it is more common to use the notation $\|f'\|$ or $\|\frac{\partial f}{x_i}\|$ for all $i$